# When there a tie in values, select a specific one considering its value in another column

Tags: r

I am working with R studio.

I have a data set that looks like this...

```
Condition  TargetWord             WordProduced        WPcondition    realValue
1          Target1                  table                 P              .009
1          Target1                  word                  P              .025
1          Target1                  chair                 P              .005
1          Target1                  pole                  Q              .015
1          Target1                  skate                 Q              .023
1          Target2                  car                   Q              .014
1          Target2                  house                 P              .014
1          Target2                  shoes                 P              .019
1          Target2                  girl                  Q              .011
1          Target2                  life                  Q              .020
1          Target3                  computer              Q              .007
1          Target3                  ball                  Q              .007
1          Target3                  court                 P              .009
1          Target3                  plane                 Q              .035
1          Target3                  sky                   O              .008
2          Target4                  tree                  P              .051
2          Target4                  five                  P              .051
2          Target4                  help                  Q              .003
2          Target4                  shave                 Q              .006
2          Target4                  love                  P              .028
2          Target5                  three                 P              .056
2          Target5                  file                  Q              .056
2          Target5                  hemp                  P              .003
2          Target5                  share                 P              .006
2          Target5                  long                  Q              .028
2          Target6                  ten                   Q              .058
2          Target6                  friend                P              .051
2          Target6                  hail                  Q              .003
2          Target6                  shine                 P              .006
2          Target6                  loner                 P              .028
```

So, every target is repeated five times and I need to filter for the first. The problem that I have is that if the reaValue is the same (.014 & .014) in the first two positions I  need the one have a value of P under the WPcondition.

This is, before filtering for the first position, if I have a tie of the realValue within the first two positions, then I need to look at the column at left (WPcondition) to see if one of them is a P. If one of them it is a P, then I need to have that one in the first position.

Let's say...

```
1position  P   .05
2position  P   .05
(stay with the one that it is in the first position) 

1position  Q   .05
2position  P   .05
(Use the one that it is in the second position because it has a P)

1position  Q   .05
2position  Q   .05
(stay with the one that it is in the first position)

1position  P   .05
2position  Q   .05
(stay with the one that it is in the first position)

1position  P   .06
2position  Q   .05
(stay with the one that it is in the first position because the realValue is higher)

1position  Q   .06
2position  P   .05
(stay with the one that it is in the first position because the realValue is higher)
```

So, I need to stay with the one that has the higher value, but if the value is the same we need to considerate the P&Q value and if There is a P, the choose that one.

Considering the above data I expect something like this...

```
Condition   TargetWord     WordProduced   WPcondition    realValue
  1          Target1           word            P            .025
  1          Target2           house           P            .014
  1          Target3           computer        Q            .007
  1          Target4           tree            P            .051
  1          Target5           three           P            .056
  1          Target6           ten             Q            .058
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: For Target1 the highest value is `0.025`. Why do you select `.009` ? Also the `WordProduced` for 0.009 is `table` and not `word` as you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. It was my mistake. The wordProduced "word" is the one with the highest value as you mention (0.025) but I wrongly wrote .009. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you clearly you want to select the row with highest `realValue` for each `TargetWord` and if there is a tie for `realValue` use `P` value over `Q`.

Taking advantage of the fact that `"P" < "Q"` we can do -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Condition, TargetWord, desc(realValue), WPcondition) %>%
  group_by(Condition, TargetWord) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup

#  Condition TargetWord WordProduced WPcondition realValue
#      <int> <chr>      <chr>        <chr>           <dbl>
#1         1 Target1    word         P               0.025
#2         1 Target2    life         Q               0.02 
#3         1 Target3    plane        Q               0.035
#4         2 Target4    tree         P               0.051
#5         2 Target5    three        P               0.056
#6         2 Target6    ten          Q               0.058
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could sort the dataframe on 'TargetWord' and 'realValue' and then within those groups, sort on 'WPcondition'. The `order` function creates indexing sort order vectors. You then pick the first item within each TargetWord.

```
 txt <- 
"Condition  TargetWord      WordProduced       WPcondition        realValue
1          Target1                  table                 P              .009
1          Target1                  word                  P              .025
1          Target1                  chair                 P              .005
1          Target1                  pole                  Q              .015
1          Target1                  skate                 Q              .023
1          Target2                  car                   Q              .014
1          Target2                  house                 P              .014
1          Target2                  shoes                 P              .019
1          Target2                  girl                  Q              .011
 1          Target2                  life                  Q              .020
 1          Target3                  computer              Q              .007
 1          Target3                  ball                  Q              .007
 1          Target3                  court                 P              .009
 1          Target3                  plane                 Q              .035
 1          Target3                  sky                   O              .008
 2          Target4                  tree                  P              .051
 2          Target4                  five                  P              .051
 2          Target4                  help                  Q              .003
 2          Target4                  shave                 Q              .006
 2          Target4                  love                  P              .028
 2          Target5                  three                 P              .056
 2          Target5                  file                  Q              .056
 2          Target5                  hemp                  P              .003
 2          Target5                  share                 P              .006
 2          Target5                  long                  Q              .028
 2          Target6                  ten                   Q              .058
 2          Target6                  friend                P              .051
 2          Target6                  hail                  Q              .003
 2          Target6                  shine                 P              .006
 2          Target6                  loner                 P              .028"
```

That's the MCVE. Here's the test code.

```
> dat <- read.table(text=txt, head=T)

 dat2 <- dat[ with(dat, order(TargetWord, realValue, WPcondition) ), ]
 # ave with `seq_along` creates an index vector within each TargetWord value.
 dat2$tseq <- ave(dat2$WPcondition, dat2$TargetWord, FUN=seq_along)
 dat2[ dat2$tseq==1, ]
#---------------------
   Condition TargetWord WordProduced WPcondition realValue tseq
3          1    Target1        chair           P     0.005    1
9          1    Target2         girl           Q     0.011    1
11         1    Target3     computer           Q     0.007    1
18         2    Target4         help           Q     0.003    1
23         2    Target5         hemp           P     0.003    1
28         2    Target6         hail           Q     0.003    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to IRTFM's answer but with the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[order(Condition,TargetWord,realValue,WPcondition),.SD[1,],"TargetWord"]


   TargetWord Condition WordProduced WPcondition realValue
1:    Target1         1        chair           P     0.005
2:    Target2         1         girl           Q     0.011
3:    Target3         1     computer           Q     0.007
4:    Target4         2         help           Q     0.003
5:    Target5         2         hemp           P     0.003
6:    Target6         2         hail           Q     0.003
>
```

Comment: Might be clearer to the new users of data.table to add the name of the third argument to `[.data.table`. And maybe also explain what `.SD[1,]` is doing and how it gets evaluated?